# MySQL strange results with subquery, inner join and order by

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-order-by, inner-join, having

I experienced a strange query behavior and I can't tell why it doesn't work as I expected.

Here is a clear reproduction of the problem:

```
create table A (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  primary key (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table B (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  a_id int not null,
  qty double not null,
  primary key (id),
  key IDX_A (a_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table C (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  b_id int not null,
  qty double not null,
  primary key (id),
  key IDX_B (b_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into A (id) values (1);

insert into B (id, a_id, qty) values (1, 1, 10);
insert into B (id, a_id, qty) values (2, 1, 15);
insert into B (id, a_id, qty) values (3, 1, 2);

insert into C (id, b_id, qty) values (1, 1, 7);
insert into C (id, b_id, qty) values (2, 1, 3);
insert into C (id, b_id, qty) values (3, 2, 3);

ALTER TABLE `B` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BA FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A (id);
ALTER TABLE `C` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CB FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B (id);
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
  b.id as b_id,
  b.qty as b_qty
FROM 
  B b
  INNER JOIN A a ON B.a_id = A.id 
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM C c 
    WHERE 
      c.b_id = b.id 
    HAVING 
      sum(c.qty) = b.qty
  )
ORDER BY b.id
```

I am expecting this result:

```
+------+-------+
| b_id | b_qty |
+------+-------+
|    1 |    10 |
+------+-------+
```

But this query gives an empty result set somehow.

A bit of interest:

When I removed "**b.qty**" from the select clause it worked fine.
It's also worked if I removed the inner join or the order by clause.

Am I failing or is this a bug?

Tested on 5.6.26 and 5.5.34.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to require that the columns in the HAVING clause be included in the     SELECT list, the following works:

```
SELECT 
  b.id AS b_id,
  b.qty AS b_qty
FROM 
  B b
  INNER JOIN A a ON b.a_id = a.id 
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT b.qty,SUM(c.qty) FROM C c 
    WHERE 
      c.b_id = b.id 
    HAVING 
      SUM(c.qty) = b.qty
  )
ORDER BY b.id;
```

Still looks like quite odd behavior. 
Analysing it I see that pulling out the sub select it actually gives an error if you don`t include the columns, this gives an error:

```
SELECT 1 FROM C c ,B b
WHERE 
c.b_id = b.id 
GROUP BY c.b_id
HAVING 
SUM(c.qty) = b.qty
```

This does not:

```
SELECT * FROM C c ,B b
WHERE 
c.b_id = b.id 
GROUP BY c.b_id
HAVING 
SUM(c.qty) = b.qty
```

So it looks like the bug is that it should be giving an error instead of the wrong result.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I took a closer look at the docs, so I rewrote my query, because I misunderstood the funcion of the HAVING clause.
Anyway it is still a weird behavior, but your explaination was very helpful.